# Why segmentation fault (core dumped) when I reverse LinkList?

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault, reverse

i write a code slip, to reverse linklist.
\
but it cause segmentation fault,i don't know why??

```
  ListNode* ReverseList(ListNode* pHead) {
    ListNode *ptr_back, *ptr_cur, *tmp;
    ptr_cur = pHead;
    ptr_back = pHead->next;
    ptr_cur->next = NULL;
    while(ptr_back){
        tmp = ptr_back->next;
        ptr_back->next = ptr_cur;
        ptr_cur = ptr_back;
        ptr_back = tmp;
    }
    return ptr_cur;
}
```

Comment: There could be multiple issues here.
For example, how do you know pHead->next is a valid ptr?

I feel like the question is lacking details.

Comment: Yes this code could be perfect (looks reasonable to me) but the code that sets up the list is bugged.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @Sir Donnie you're right!pHead->next may not a valid pointer to ListNode,so it possiblely don't have next pointer,and pHead->next->next cause segmentation.

Comment: @ Jesper Juhl,I feel sorry for not having a complete example.But it's a problem one of OJ(nowcode.com),I also don't know which test example failed my code.

Answer (score 1):

ThANKS @Sir Donnie
I change my code.And it work!

```
 ListNode* ReverseList(ListNode* pHead) {
  ListNode *ptr_back=pHead;
  ListNode *ptr_cur=NULL;
  ListNode *tmp = NULL;
    while(ptr_back!=NULL){
        tmp = ptr_back->next;
        ptr_back->next = ptr_cur;
        ptr_cur = ptr_back;
        ptr_back = tmp;
    }
    return ptr_cur;
}
```